# Netsuite Client Script only Executes in Testing Mode

Tags: javascript, oracle, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I have a simple client script that works fine in testing mode.  But once I deploy it, it stops executing.

```
/**
 * @author Patrick 
 * @NApiVersion 2.x 
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
 */
define(['N/ui/message', 'N/record'],
    function(message, record) {

        function pageInit(context) {
            var purchaseOrder = context.currentRecord;
            log.debug(purchaseOrder);

            return true;
        }

        return {
          pageInit: pageInit
        }
    }
);
```

[image]

This deployment works.  But once I switch it to deployed it stops working. Any suggestions on what I am missing would be a great help. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you deploy a script you generally need to set the Audience.
Otherwise you get what you have just observed.

Comment: I thought I had the audience set, but after playing around with different settings, it started working.  I feel like I also had to hit refresh on the PO page too.  Anyway it working now thank you for the feedback.